# Multi Modular Project with SBT 0.11.0

Tags: scala, sbt

Looking for examples / references of a multiple modular project with SBT 0.11.0. All the examples I found were for older versions of SBT.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you should really look at the "[Full Configuration](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration)" example on the sbt wiki first.

When you are done with that, and you still want more, head over to github. These days all my build inspiration comes from the [Scalatra build file](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/blob/develop/project/build.scala). It's really nicely done!

Comment: Full configuration documentation has moved to here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def

Answer (score 0):

You need to use FullConfiguration to setup modular projects, Basic Configuration can't do.

The wiki of SBT0.11.0 on github gives samples on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get inspired by the Akka project, found in https://github.com/akka/akka